# Extracting median from databases of n entries using O(log n) queries

Tags: algorithm

Suppose I have two databases each containing `n` entries. Define median to be the `n`'th smallest value. We can extract one value, at a time, from a given database through query.

`Query(k)` returns `k`'th smallest value of the database specified. How can you find the median using at most `O(log n)` queries ?

Comment: All values may be assumed to be distinct.

Comment: What language, what kind of database? Please tag accordingly

Comment: First, the `n`th smallest value of `n` entries is the maximum value, not the median value. Second, if `Query(k)` returns `k`th smallest value, then you need only one query – `Query(n/2)`.

Comment: @arekolek I agreed with you first but then re-read and there are **two** databases, each of `n` entries, and we want the median of the *combined* set of values.

Answer (score 2):

The required time complexity is `O(log n)` which indicates that we should give a try to find a binary search approach. Similar to but slight different from binary search, we still divide `n` into two halves each time.

```
// As Query(k) will return k'th smallest element, considering database as container of sorted entries for understanding purpose. 
E.g., DB1 = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]  DB2 = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]. n = 5.

i = n / 2 = 2;
j = n - i = 3;

        i 
DB1 [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]

          j
DB2[2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
```

if `DB1.Query(i) < DB2.Query(j)`, which means the elements from `1` to `i` inclusive of `DB1` must exist in the first `n` elements.

The next step now becomes finding the `(n - i)`th (equals to `n / 2`) element in the `DB1`(from `i + 1` to `n`) and `DB2`(from `1` to `n`).  This procedure can be viewed as "cutting" `n / 2` elements from one database, and continue finding the other `n / 2`th elements from the other database and the "new" database after the cut.

if `DB1.Query(i) > DB2.Query(j)`, the same procedure is applied but we "cut" the `DB2` database.

In this way, every time we have "cut" `n / 2` elements from one of the databases, the next time is to cut `(n / 2) / 2` elements from that database, until:

- `n = 1`, the smaller one from `DB1.Query(1)` and `DB2.Query(1)` is the "nth element".
- One of the databases meets the end. Then just return the current `n`th element from the other database.

Here I've assumed `DB1` and `DB2` are database handlers of two databases. This syntax is similar to C++ but you can get the idea. This ensures `O(log n)` complexity.

```
// Find k'th smallest element of the two combind database entries
int findMedianofDatabaseHelper(DBHandler* db1, int i, DBHandler* db2, int j, const int n, int k) {
    if((n - i) > (n - j))
    {
        return findMedianofDatabaseHelper(db2, j, db1, i, n, k);
    }
    if(i >= n)
    {
        return db2->Query(j + k);
    }
    if(j >= n)
    {
        return db1->Query(i + k);
    }
    if(k == 1)
    {
        return min(db1->Query(i + 1), db2->Query(j + 1));
    }

    int aMid = min(k / 2, n - i);
    int bMid = k - aMid;

    if(db1->Query(i + aMid) <= db2->Query(j + bMid))
    {
        return findMedianofDatabaseHelper(db1, i + aMid, db2, j, n, k - aMid);
    }

    return findMedianofDatabaseHelper(db1, i, db2, j + bMid, n, k - bMid);
}

// assuming DBHandler is a wrapper of database handler/instance on which we can perform query
int findMedianofDatabase(DBHandler* db1, DBHandler* db2, int n)
{
    return findMedianofDatabaseHelper(db1, 0, db2, 0, n, n);
}
```

[Here](https://ideone.com/Jf9P94) I simulated the working program in C++.

Comment: @SauravSahu Thanks! I've added some explanation and also a simulation program in my answer. Take a look :)

Answer (score 0):

You can essentially find this with binary search (up to some adjustment if n is not a power of 2): query for the `n/2`-smallest elements `m1, m2` in the two databases. If they are equal, then you have your median. If `m1<m2`, then ask for the `3n/4`-th smallest in the first and the `1/4`-th smallest in the second, and vice versa if `m1>m2`. Repeat.

In each step you have the same number of elements below as above the chosen elements.